# autosuspend on GNOME45 not working as expected

Tags: suspend, power-management, xrdp, gnome-tweaks, systemd-logind

I am confused about how autosuspend works and how to configure it correctly. Upgraded to gnome45 recently and the auto suspend after X mins option wasn't present in power settings. my usecase here is I have my machine plugged in all the time and configured wireless wake-on-lan to remotely wake it up and automatically suspend on inactivity (no local session or remote). I have tried the following options but don't really understand what they are doing underneath and am not getting the desired behavior (it goes into suspend even if there is an active remote session). Can someone provide more context on each of the following?

- AllowSuspend and SuspendMode in /etc/systemd/sleep.conf
- HandleLidSwitch and HandleSuspendKey in /etc/systemd/logind.conf
- sleep-inactive-ac-timeout in /etc/./gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
- Adding <Option "SuspendTime" "0"> under ServiceLayout within /etc/X11/xrdp/xorg.conf
- gnome tweaks suspend on lid

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement